# mobile backend starter error: 404 not found

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

I am trying the example of Google Mobile Backend Starter and everything works fine until I run the guestbook application. When I write and send a message I get a GoogleJsonResponseException 404 Not Found

I followed the instructions in this tutorial
  https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/getting_started

Any idea? Seem not find the backend? When I try connect to
  https://[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/_ah/api/
I get the same Not Found error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im getting the same error (as a toast in my android app). Im trying the Guestbook sample in Android Studio. The backend seems to be deployed and opened correctly (I just redid it with a new project) And I did not forget to set the PROJECT_ID in the Consts.java file

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error and did as Romin suggested in one of the comments on Brad Abrams' answer: I simply re-deployed the mobile backend starter in the Google Cloud Console. No idea why, but it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: breadbin after redeploy I used @Zzokk answer as well to set to locked down and then to open, and then started working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying out the Mobile Backend Stater...

In the android project, have you replaced the PROJECT_ID with the the project ID from the cloud console project you created?  Looks like that might be the issue..

Comment: Yes, I replaced the PROJECT_ID in Consts.java file with the Application Identifier found in the cloud console.

Comment: Yes, I replaced the PROJECT_ID in the Consts.java file with the Application Identifier found in the cloud console, but it looks like that PROJECT_ID does not work because I've tried with the ID of a partner's project and then the android application suddenly worked in the correct way. If you want I can provide more information of my project to find out what may have happened. Thanks for your help Brad :)

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I just tried it out and came across the same issue. I then created a new project on cloud.google.com and replaced new project id in my project and it worked. Just make sure that you select "Open" for authentication under Mobile Backend Settings (for development purpose only).

Comment: I found a similar issue. I resolved it by doing a redeploy of the project and that seems to have solved the problem for now. But yes, it is important to understand the root cause.

Comment: One more thing that helped me was changing to "Locked Down" in the settings paged, saving the new value and then back to the "Open" mode.

Comment: @Zzokk that helped for me too after redeploy

Comment: For some reason the re-deploy link did not show up on my project. I deleted the project and recreated a new project. I followed the steps above regarding the save to locked and then open again. I deleted the project in Eclipse and downloaded a new zip file.... for the, "WEB_CLIENT_ID" I used a key generated under, "Key for browser apps" ...it works!

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that the version being used in your code is different from the app engine default version.

The app engine default version is deployed to:
http://[appversion]-your-product-id.appspot.com
The code you are running though has specified the deployment version as 1 which means when deployed, your app will check here:
http://1-dot-your-project-id.appspot.com hence the 404 (because in essence, this URL doesn't exit. I use one here for illustration purposes).

To resolve this, go to https://appengine.google.com/deployment?app_id=s~your-project-id and make the version you've uploaded the default version

More here:
 [App Engine Set-up hiccups](http://kakoma.ug/code/2014/02/android-dev-tutorial-setting-app-engine-connected-app-hiccups/)